# Read, subset and bind many .txt files in R

Tags: r

I would like to read many .txt files, ignoring the first line and just getting the fifth column. After that, merge all these columns extracted into a data.frame.

I made these with a for loop, building a lot of variables with assign() and then getting all with mget(ls()).

Is there any faster way to do this?

Here are three of these files: `we.tl/t-JcVsfiUPLv`

Comment: You can include the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign` should usually be avoided and in this case we don't need to create these objects in global environment. Try using `lapply`.

```
#List all text files in the working directory
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.txt$')
#Read every text file with header, skipping the 1st row. 
#Keep only the 5th column after reading the data. 
result <- lapply(filenames, function(x) read.table(x,skip = 1,header = TRUE)[,5])
result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And then i would use something like cbind? I still need to join these vectors in a single table

Comment: `do.call(cbind, result)` ?